# Does vsftpd support POSIX Acls?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, access-control-list, ftp

I have a ftp site with about 1000 users running vsftpd on Ubuntu 10.04 Server. I now need a more fine-grained rights management and the normal user,group,world is not sufficient anymore. Because of that I mounted my ext4 filesystem with POSIX Acls enabled. 
Is there an option I need to apply in the configuration so that vsftpd honors the acls? Or doesn't it event support them?

Comment: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/VirtualVsFtpd discusses using MySQL as an ACL backend, and http://www.mail-archive.com/linux-il@cs.huji.ac.il/msg43821.html seems to indicate that vsftpd will honor the filesystem's ACLs - but I have never tried either :)

Answer (score 2):

Vsftpd does not support them. This means it is not possible to modify the ACLs with a FTP client. But vsftpd has no other choice but to honor them, because the kernel prevents vsftpd to do anything, that is permitted by the ACLs.